# Finding a linear function given eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a linear function $f$ and I know that the function $f_\mathbb C : x + iy \mapsto f(x) + if(y)$ with $x,y \in \mathbb R^{3 \times 1}$ has three eigenvectors: $$v_1 = (1,1,-1)^T, v_2=(0,1,i)^T,v_3 = (0,1,-i)^T$$
with three corresponding eigenvalues:
$$t_1=0,t_2=i,t_3=-i$$

My goal is to show that such a function $f$ exists and find it's coordinate matrix.

I started by writing out the definitions, for example:
$$f_\mathbb C (v_2) = f((0,1,0)^T)+if((0,0,1)^T)= if((0,1,0)^T)-f((0,0,1)^T)$$

I simplified all the statements and ended up with (let $e_i$ stand for the canonical basis vectors):
$$f(e_1)+f(e_2)-f(e_3) = 0$$
$$(1-i)f(e_2)+(1+i)f(e_3)=0$$
$$(1+i)f(e_2)+(1-i)f(e_3)=0$$

Here is where I get stuck. I am pretty sure the above result is correct, but what do I do from here? I thought of solving a system of linear equations, but I cannot do that for vectors, or can I? Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is the matrix I got:
$$\langle E^*,f_\mathbb C (E)\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0  \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
i & 0 & i
\end{pmatrix}$$

This seems to be right, since I tested it for the eigenvectors and the right values came out. But this matrix should theoretically be equal to the matrix of $f$, since both maps act the same on real vectors. It cannot be quite right though, since I am looking for a map from $\mathbb R^{3 \times 1}$  to $\mathbb R^{3 \times 1}$

Comment: Hint: The eigenvectors give you a basis in which the matrix is diagonal.

Comment: @amd I am not quite sure how to find this matrix. I mean, I would know that for this basis, the first column of the matrix for $f_\mathbb C$ would only be zeros, but I cannot say much about the other two, since $f_\mathbb C (v_2)$ has other unknowns in it, which I do not know, but rather want to find out

Comment: What is $f(v)$ when $v$ is an eigenvector of $f$?

Comment: @amd It usually is $t*v$ for the eigenvalue $t$ , but I only have eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $f_\mathbb C$ ... I might be blind right now but I dont see it... I might have made a mistake above though

Comment: Let’s try a different tack, then. What does the definition of $f_{\mathbb C}$ say when $y=0$?

Comment: @amd Ahh okay, I see now where I was running against the wall in my head.. I found the matrix now for $f_\mathbb C$. Now I should be able to change this to the canonical basis and then find out the matrix of $f$, right?

Comment: Sounds about right to me. Post whatever you come up with as an answer once the site allows you to do so.

Comment: @amd uh oh.. I think something here is not right though. I found the matrix (Ill update the question) but it contains complex entries. However, the linear map $f$ should be a map from $\mathbb R^{3\times 1 }$ to $\mathbb R^{3\times 1 }$

Comment: Without seeing how you got this matrix, it’s hard to say, but it’s likely you computed the change of basis incorrectly. Also, are you sure you computed your tests correctly? Your matrix obviously has rank 1, so has 0 as a double eigenvalue. At least one of tne of the tests against the given non-zero eigenvalues should’ve failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions of the problem basically say that $f:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$. We’re given all of the eigenvalues and some corresponding eigenvectors, so finding its matrix is a matter of applying a change of basis to a diagonal matrix. It’s easy to forget on which side of the matrix multiplication that this entails to put the inverse matrix, but you’ll never go wrong if you start from the “bulk” version of the eigenvalue/eigenvector equation $AP=P\Lambda$. Here $\Lambda=\operatorname{diag}(0,i,-i)$ and in the standard basis $P=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&1\\-1&i&-i\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ so the matrix of $f$ in the standard basis is $P\Lambda P^{-1}=\dots$?

Comment: Okay, I got it. I did the steps right, but apparently my calculator did not compute the inverse corrrectly, although I double checked. Thanks again